# Bug running Airflow with Docker to ingest data to GCP Mounts denied: The path /.google/credentials/google_credentials.json is not shared from the host

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose, airflow, pipeline

I am running an Airflow workflow in Docker to ingest data into GCP but I keep getting this error message in the terminal.

After trying the following docker compose command I get the following errors

```
$ docker compose build
$ docker compose up
```

Error:

```
Error response from daemon: Mounts denied:
The path /.google/credentials/google_credentials.json is not shared from the host and is not known to Docker.
You can configure shared paths from Docker -> Preferences... -> Resources -> File Sharing.
```

Below is the file structure and Docker YAML file too

YAML

```
version: "3"
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - postgres-db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "airflow"]
      interval: 5s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  scheduler:
    build: .
    command: scheduler
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
      - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
      - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
      - ./scripts:/opt/airflow/scripts
      - ~/.google/credentials/:/.google/credentials.json

  webserver:
    build: .
    entrypoint: ./scripts/entrypoint.sh
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - scheduler
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
      - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
      - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
      - /.google/credentials/google_credentials.json:/.google/credentials:ro
      - ./scripts:/opt/airflow/scripts

    user: "${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:0"
    ports:
      - "8082:8080"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "[ -f /home/airflow/airflow-webserver.pid ]"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 3

volumes:
  postgres-db-volume:
```

enviroment file <.env>

```
AIRFLOW_UID=50000

#PG_HOST=pgdatabase
#PG_USER=root
#PG_PASSWORD=root
#PG_PORT=5432
#PG_DATABASE=ny_taxi

# Custom
COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=de-queries
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/.google/credentials/google_credentials.json
AIRFLOW_CONN_GOOGLE_CLOUD_DEFAULT=google-cloud-platform://?extra__google_cloud_platform__key_path=/.google/credentials/google_credentials.json
# AIRFLOW_UID=
GCP_PROJECT_ID=
GCP_GCS_BUCKET=

# Postgres
POSTGRES_USER=airflow
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=airflow
POSTGRES_DB=airflow

# Airflow
AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR=LocalExecutor
AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__SCHEDULER_HEARTBEAT_SEC=10

AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN=postgresql+psycopg2://${POSTGRES_USER}:${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}@postgres:5432/${POSTGRES_DB}
AIRFLOW_CONN_METADATA_DB=postgres+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres:5432/airflow
AIRFLOW_VAR__METADATA_DB_SCHEMA=airflow

_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_CREATE=True
_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME=airflow
_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD=airflow

AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION=True
AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES=False
```

shell file <.sh>

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=${GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS}
export AIRFLOW_CONN_GOOGLE_CLOUD_DEFAULT=${AIRFLOW_CONN_GOOGLE_CLOUD_DEFAULT}

airflow db upgrade

airflow users create -r Admin -u admin -p admin -e admin@example.com -f admin -l airflow
# "$_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME" -p "$_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD"

airflow webserver
```

I have tried changing my environment variable to a relative path

`GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=Users/<username>/.google/credentials/google_credentials.json`

I have also tried using the terminal to export the path with

`export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/.google/credentials/google_credentials.json`

Comment: In the service `webserver`, you try to mount the path `/.google/credentials/google_credentials.json`. Does this path exist in the host system? Is this a typo, e.g., you want to mount `~/.google/...` instead?

Comment: yes, this path exists on my host system. Thanks for spotting that typo error and it fix it